# akka or similar alternative for golang to support distributed concurrency?

Tags: go, distributed-computing

I know golang is very good at concurrency with its built-in support, but seems to me they are not distributed, so what would be the framework/library allow us to write producers/consumers applications, in a distributed environment.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use Go's channel concepts in a distributed program, perhaps check out the [Go Circuit](http://www.gocircuit.org/) framework.

It provides a framework for running multi-process programs (possibly spread over multiple machines), allowing you to use channels to communicate between those processes.

Comment: This is a better idea than trying to adopt Akka in Go. The concurrency model of Akka is based on the actor model of Erlang, which operates (only) by putting messages into the single input queue of your target actor. It is not possible to write data-driven synchronised structures. Conversely, in Go, the basic channel model is of synchronous/blocking message passing. It is easy to buffer this when the sender and receiver are to be decoupled. Go gets the best of both approaches and is more general than the Akka model.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more on the pros and cons of Akka concurrency model vs Go's channel based approach? Or any source I can find this information?

Comment: @Rick-777 - can you please elaborate more about inability of the data-driven synchronized structures in Akka? In Akka you can synchronize, although the idea is that you try to have as little synchronization as possible.

Comment: Quite simply, Akka is a restricted, limited concurrency model. It achieves certain things _very_ well; especially, distributed computing with fault tolerance is its forte. However, CSP is *fundamentally* a more general concurrency model. With CSP, you can do what Akka does if you want to. But you don't have to. With Akka you are tied to the callback model - Akka's actors provide a nice encapsulation of callbacks to handle message receipt; but that's as far as it goes. How do you do lock-step data-driven flow control in, say, robotics? Akka cannot, but CSP can.

Answer (score 10):

No need to reinvent the wheel here... producer/Consumer applications are usually built using a message queue.

With this approach you should try to break up your problem into small (and ideally idempotent) tasks, build an application which can enqueue these tasks, and then have another worker application which can dequeue these tasks and execute them. Scaling is easy: just add more workers.

There are lots of queuing solutions out there, for a very good one written in Go take a look at [NSQ](https://github.com/bitly/nsq).

Comment: or save yourself a huge headache and use Erlang or Elixir, which were meant to be used this way, and give you much more including supervision.

Comment: Go was also designed to be used to develop distributed systems. Distributed systems development is not easy and no framework will make it easy.

Comment: Erlang is not a "framework". It is a feature-complete programming language that excels at distributed computing. Elixir is a more modern variant of the language. Both are FAR superior to Golang if your use case is multi-node distributed computing. Golang is strong on concurrency *only* on a single box. For crossing machine boundaries, with Golang you're no better off than using C.

Answer (score 7):

Two years late but if anyone else is looking.
https://github.com/AsynkronIT/gam

GAM (Go Actor Model) supports both Akka like actors, and Ms Orleans like Virtual Grains.
The Ms Orleans like Virtual Grains are supported via Protobuf code generation to give you typed messages and typed grain types.
See 
https://github.com/AsynkronIT/gam/blob/dev/examples/cluster/member/main.go
https://github.com/AsynkronIT/gam/blob/dev/examples/cluster/shared/protos.proto

It's also extremely fast, 1 mil+ remote messages per sec.

Answer (score 6):

Akka is based on the Actor Model. For that, there is a nice Go framework I invite you to test : https://github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go

It is said to have great performance since it claims to be passing between nodes:

> two million messages per second

While Go is already implementing using CSP, Protoactor adds :

- Decoupled Concurrency
- Distributed by default
- Fault tolerance

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record [NATS](http://nats.io/) is a high performance solution for distributed systems. It's open source and under [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) license. "The core NATS Server acts as a central nervous system for building distributed applications." and it has official [clients](http://nats.io/download/) for Go, C#, Java, Ruby, Python, Node.js and much more provided by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Such an old question but I would check out [dapr](https://dapr.io/) and [protoactor](https://github.com/asynkron/protoactor-go).

dapr is more flexible but carries overhead from employing a sidecar pattern.

protoactor is more like akka having been written by the same guy who made akka.net.

Both are good depending on your use case. This [blog does](https://www.etteplan.com/stories/benchmark-net-virtual-actor-frameworks) a good comparison of the performance.